# Uniformly Continous $\delta - \epsilon$ proof

Tags: real-analysis

Let f and g be uniformly continuous on an interval S.

Show that fg is uniformly continuous on S if S is closed.

I am having trouble understanding skipped steps in the proof:

Assume S is closed.

(lemma) Then $\exists$ A,B such that |f(x)|< A and |g(x)|< B, $\forall x \in$ S.

Hence *|(fg)(x) - (fg)(y)| $\leq$ |f(x)||g(x)-g(y)|+|g(y)||f(x)-f(y)|

I don't understand why * is true.

Comment: That's not true. If $S=\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=g(x)=x$, then $fg$ is not uniformly continuous. I guess you want to assume that $S$ is compact. Without this compactness assumption, I don't see why both $f$ and $g$ are bounded as your lemma claims.

Comment: @AlexFok $S$ is said to be a closed interval.

Comment: $S$ may be unbounded and closed.

Comment: the lemma is from the min-max thm where we assume bounded.

Comment: Can you state your min-max theorem? A uniformly continuous function may be unbounded on an unbounded interval, as my example shows.

Comment: a function f:[a,b]$\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bounded if there exists a B in reals such that |f(x)| $\leq$ B for all x $\in$ [a,b] Lemma follows.

Comment: I see. You have implicitly assumed that $S$ is a bounded closed interval, which you did not state in your question clearly. A closed interval may be unbounded, like $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming $fg$ means the function that takes the value $ f(x)g(x) $ at $x$ and not the composition. Then  $(*)$ follows from,

$$ |f(x)g(x) - f(y)g(y) | = | f(x)g(x) - f(x)g(y) + f(x)g(y) - f(y)g(y) | $$

and the Triangle Inequality.